# What is the best method to define variables in java?

Tags: java

I've been working with java in a year now, and since java formatting can be done how you want, I'm now seeking the optimal method to define variables :-)

Let's say I want to create a new class with some fields:

```
public class Email {
    private String from, to, date, subject, content;
    public Email(String from, String to, String date, String subject, String content ) {
        this.from = from; 
// and so on...
```

Would that be better than doing it line for line like this?

```
public class Email {
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String date;
    private String subject;
    private String content;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of cousre none of these is *better*. Both are valid and produce the same bytecode.

The first option is less verbose but it can get difficult to read if there are many variables. It makes refactoring more difficult.

The second option is verbose but it makes the types of each variable obvious.

Many organizations have coding standards that allow only one of these options, typically the second one.

By the way, it might not be the best idea to use a `String`to represent a date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what type would you represent a date with?

Comment: @user3010171: There is a `Date` class and corresponding `Calendar` classes in Java. Some advantages over `String` are the ability to sort and to convert between different formats.